# Абракадабра при отправке писем из FireFox (PHP)

Tags: php, сервер, браузер

Кодировка `windows-1251`.
На сайте есть блок отправки "жалобы".
Функция для отправки - `mail(PHP)` , язык - `рус/укр`.

Когда письмо отправляется из `Chrome/IE`, письмо приходит с нормальным отображаемым текстом, но вот когда  из `FireFox` - абракадабра на `укр/рус`, а на латинице - норма.

Пробовал перекодировать файл в разные кодировки, устанавливал header - результата нет.

Comment: А текст на сайте без абракадабры?

Comment: выложите свой код

Comment: Отправка отдельным скриптом, который вызывается тем и ли иным способом с формы html страницы, или же и страница и отправка - это единый php-файл?

Comment: Текст на сайте нормально отображается.

Comment: По поводу кода. Код обычный: получаю данные с формы - и через ajax

Comment: ajax отправляю скрипту header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251'); проверяю $_POST и вперед в mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы отправляете скрипту header, а кроме попробуйте установить header для функции mail. Вот, например,  так:

```
public function sendMail($to, $subject, $message, $html = true) {
    $headers = 'From: YOU EMAIL <YOU_EMAIL@DOMAIN.DOMAIN>' . "\r\n" .
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=YOU_CHARSET"' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Доброго дня!**
Мое мнение - не извращаться с win, koi и другими кодировками. Используйте только UTF-8. Проблем не будет, т.к. там содержаться все необходимые символы.

Comment: Это само собой. Но не вариант - для данного проекта

Answer (score 0):

Решено.Переустановка win1251 на сервере и все ок.

Comment: Что? Какая переустановка? Где? На каком сервере? Раскройте ваш ответ, пожалуйста.